# Acl9 association table created_at column issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, acl9

I'm trying to figure out why the created_at column of roles_users' table seems to take the user one when assigning a role to a user. It should not have its own creation date? Any helps?

> ruby-1.8.7-p174 > Time.now
>    => **Thu Feb 24 15:50:11 +0100 2011**
>   ruby-1.8.7-p174 > User.last.has_role! "installer"
>     *User Load (0.5ms)   SELECT * FROM "users" ORDER BY users.id DESC LIMIT 1
>
>     Country Load (0.2ms)   SELECT * FROM "countries" WHERE ("countries"."id" = 106)
>
>     Role Load (0.2ms)   SELECT * FROM "roles" WHERE (name = 'installer' and authorizable_type IS NULL and authorizable_id IS NULL) LIMIT 1
>
>     Role Load (0.1ms)   SELECT "roles".id FROM "roles" INNER JOIN "roles_users" ON "roles".id = "roles_users".role_id WHERE ("roles"."id" = 2) AND ("roles_users".user_id = 31 ) LIMIT 1
>
>     SQL (0.3ms)   INSERT INTO "roles_users" ("created_at", "updated_at", "role_id", "user_id") VALUES ('**2010-09-16 14:11:24**', '**2010-09-16 14:11:24**', 2, 31)
>
>     Role Load (0.5ms)   SELECT * FROM "roles" INNER JOIN "roles_users" ON "roles".id = "roles_users".role_id WHERE ("roles_users".user_id = 31 )
>
>    => [#Role id: 2, name: "installer", authorizable_type: nil, authorizable_id: nil, created_at: "2010-09-16 14:11:24", updated_at: "2010-09-16 14:11:24">]*
>
>   ruby-1.8.7-p174 > Role.find_by_name("installer")
>     *Role Load (0.3ms)   SELECT * FROM "roles" WHERE ("roles"."name" = 'installer') LIMIT 1*
>
>    => #Role id: 2, name: "installer", authorizable_type: nil, authorizable_id: nil, created_at: "**2010-09-16 14:11:24**", updated_at: "2010-09-16 14:11:24">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the habtm join table used by acl9 might not have additional attributes.

if in the join table there'is created_at or updated_at attributes ActiveRecord populate this value with the value of associated table (Role in your case) .

If you want this functionality you have to edit the gem and add some :after_add callback filter to the relations, look at row 41 of this [file](https://github.com/be9/acl9/blob/v0.12.0/lib/acl9/model_extensions.rb)

also, updated_at is useless because the row in the join db table was created and removed ,never updated...

hope this could help , sorry for my english .

Answer (score 0):

This really was caused by an error in the acl9 docs (because a habtm join table shouldn't have timestamps). I fixed [the docs](https://github.com/be9/acl9/wiki/Role-Subsystem#subject-model) too, and acl9 1.2 now has a generator for that migration too :)